Philips HUE Motion Sensor - bug into brightness management
After first setting, motion sensor works correctly and do not turn on the lights when motion is detected and room brightness is above the set threshold.
When the dark comes, motion sensor works correctly and turn on the lights when motion is detected and room brightness is below the set threshold.
When daylight return, motion sensor not works correctly and turn on the lights when motion is detected even if room brightness is above the set threshold.
At this point ,you have to save again the same setting threshold, and restart with the same problem !
tested with 3 different sensors, all test possible performed with Philips Support, app reinstalled, all devices and bridge and router reset etc., they told me that’s a software bug but they cannot forward this to the developer team…
Philips Support told me to try this way, hoping that some developer can provide for a firmware update
